# Checking letter position and if its the correct letter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Im creating a game that generates a random word and then lets the user guess the word. 
After the user enters his word the game will compare them and return what letter were correct and if they had the right position. Right now it return differents results when i input the same word.

This is what i have so far:

```
class Game
{
    public string CorrectPlace;
    public string WrongPlace;
    public string NoneExist;
    public string CorrectWord;
    public string InputWord; // the word the uis
    public int points;

    public string[] Wordarray = new string[] { "radar", "andar", "raggar", "rapar", "raser", "rastar", "rikas" };

    public string getRandomWord(string names)
    {   
        Random ran = new Random();
        return Wordarray[(ran.Next(0,Wordarray.Length-1))];
    }

    public void CheckWords(string name)
    {
        InputWord.ToCharArray(); 

        CorrectWord = getRandomWord(CorrectWord); // store the random word in a string

        for (int i = 0; i < CorrectWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (InputWord[i] == CorrectWord[i])
                MessageBox.Show("Letter #" + (i + 1).ToString() + " was correct!");
            else
                break;
        }  
    }
}
```

Im calling the method in my form

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Game nc = new Game();

        nc.InputWord = textBox1.Text;
        nc.CheckWords(nc.InputWord);



        }
```

Comment: your line `InputWord.ToCharArray();` is not doing anything the result gets discarded. Its not getting used and not required at all in your current code.

Comment: Where are you using your input ? I do not see Input word being initialized anywhere. And you are comparing against random values, your logic is not clear from the code you have posted.

Comment: so your saying if you compare the same word it reports wrong?

Comment: There is no use of parameter `names` in method `getRandomWord`. Same s the case with `Checkwords`. How d you call `Checkwords` method ?

Comment: I am expecting the problem is here: `CorrectWord = getRandomWord(CorrectWord);`. Everytime you enter in `Checkwords` methods, `CorrectedWord` changes. So probably you will get wrong result.

Comment: the input is from a textbox in the form. Game nc = new Game();
 nc.InputWord = textBox1.Text;
            nc.CheckWords(nc.InputWord);

Comment: @NeverHopeless So how do i store the random word and then compare it to the user input word? Thanks

Comment: @user1808211 Why don't you implement *snake* game as most of your classmates do? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
class Game
{
    public string CorrectPlace;
    public string WrongPlace;
    public string NoneExist;
    public string CorrectWord;
    public string InputWord;  
    public int points;

    public string[] Wordarray = null;

    public string getRandomWord(string names)
    {   
        Random ran = new Random();
        return Wordarray[(ran.Next(0,Wordarray.Length-1))];
    }

    public void Game()
    {
        Wordarray = new string[] { "radar", "andar", "raggar", "rapar", "raser", "rastar", "rikas" }
        CorrectWord = getRandomWord(); // store the random word in a string
    }

    public void CheckWords(string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < CorrectWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (InputWord[i] == CorrectWord[i])
                MessageBox.Show("Letter #" + (i + 1).ToString() + " was correct!");
            else
                break;
        }  
    }
}
```

The idea behind the scene is to get a random word when game starts( an instance of class `Game` instantiated) and then compare it with the user input in `CheckWords` method.

I would suggest to do not call `MessageBox.show` in a loop, it will popup every time a match exists.
occur

Comment: @user1808211,check now. My bad, created a method instead of constructor .

Comment: The error is Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Where ? I mean on which line ? have you tried to initialize `Wordarray ` in the constructor ?

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Why do we set the value for the word array in the game method

Comment: `constructor` is designed for this purpose. i.e., to initialize or assigned some default value etc

Answer (score 0):

Change the Code Like this.  Please let me know if you have any issues.

class Game
    {

```
    public string CorrectWord = null;
    public string InputWord; // the word the uis
    public int points;

    public string[] Wordarray = new string[] { "radar", "andar", "raggar", "rapar", "raser", "rastar", "rikas" };

    public string getRandomWord()
    {
        Random ran = new Random();
        return Wordarray[(ran.Next(0, Wordarray.Length - 1))];
    }

    public void Newgame()
    {
    }

    public void CheckWords(string name)
    {

        char[] charInputWord = name.ToCharArray();


        CorrectWord = getRandomWord(); // store the random word in a string

        Console.WriteLine("Random Word " + CorrectWord);
        Console.WriteLine("User Word " + name);

        char[] charCorrectWord = CorrectWord.ToCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < charInputWord.Length; i++)
        {
            if (charInputWord[i] == charCorrectWord[i])
                Console.WriteLine("Letter #" + (i + 1).ToString() + " was correct!");
            else
                break;
        }
    }
}



class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game ab = new Game();
            ab.CheckWords("raser");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesnt this code have the same problem as mine. Refering to CorrectWord = getRandomWord();

Comment: You didn't use any Operation on that parameter. Why you need to simply pass string to that function.The Actaull thins is need to do add this code for project   char[] charInputWord = name.ToCharArray(); and char[] charCorrectWord = CorrectWord.ToCharArray(); and change for loop condition to this     for (int i = 0; i < charInputWord.Length; i++)

Answer (score 0):

Both `names` and `name` are never used, and seem unneeded.

It looks like you want something like this (converted to console printing since I don't have your UI source)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace WordGame
{
    class Game
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Game g = new Game();
            bool gameOver = false;

            while (!gameOver)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter a guess (or type 'exit' to exit):");
                string answer = Console.ReadLine();
                if (answer.ToLower() == "exit")
                    break;

                if (g.CheckWord(answer))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You win!");
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Play Again (y/n)?");
                        answer = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                        if (answer == "n")
                        {
                            gameOver = true;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (answer == "y")
                        {
                            g.ChooseRandomWord();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public string CorrectWord;

        public string[] Wordarray = new string[] { "radar", "andar", "raggar", "rapar", "raser", "rastar", "rikas" };
        private Random ran = new Random();

        public Game()
        {
            ChooseRandomWord();
        }

        public void ChooseRandomWord()
        {
            CorrectWord = Wordarray[(ran.Next(0, Wordarray.Length - 1))];
        }

        public bool CheckWord(string guess)
        {
            if (guess.Trim() == CorrectWord)
            {
                return true;
            }

            string guessLower = guess.Trim().ToLower();
            string correctLower = CorrectWord.ToLower();

            for (int i = 0; i < correctLower.Length; i++)
            {
                if (guessLower[i] == correctLower[i])
                    Console.Write(guess[i]);
                else
                    Console.Write("#");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            return false;
        }

    }
}
```